# Create Grid Using TrailwindCSS

Tags: html, css, css-grid, tailwind-css

So, I have been trying to create this grid layout (see image attachment below) using this CSS framework called TrailwindCSS; however, I am having issues with controlling/changing the width of a column. To be more specific, I was able to change the side and whatnot, but I was never satisfied with the result because either the grid was not perfectly centered (I am using a container) or because the change completely messed up the layout.

How can I create a grid layout like this using TrailwindCSS?
[image: Grid]

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<div className="bg-red-400 p-1 grid grid-cols-4 gap-4">
  {/* First row */}
  <div className="bg-blue-400 h-32 col-span-3"></div>
  <div className="bg-blue-500 h-32"></div>

  {/* Second Row */}
  <div className="bg-blue-600 h-32 col-span-4"></div>

  {/* Third Row */}
  <div className="bg-blue-700 h-32"></div>
  <div className="bg-blue-800 h-32 col-span-3"></div>
</div>
```